# Writing to PostgresSQL from pyscopg2 using StringIO - Copy slows down over time

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-rds, psycopg2

I am reading JSONs into python and parsing them in a tabular format (a pandas dataframe) before writing them to a Postgres table. The table is large (currently ~ 3GBs) and each upload is ~4000 rows.

I'm using this function to write each 4000 rows to the database.

```
def copy_from_stringio(conn, df, table):
    """
    Here we are going save the dataframe in memory
    and use copy_from() to copy it to the table
    """
    # save dataframe to an in memory buffer
    buffer = StringIO()
    df.to_csv(buffer, header=False)
    buffer.seek(0)

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.copy_from(buffer, table, sep=",",  null='')
        conn.commit()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print("Error: %s" % error)
        conn.rollback()
        cursor.close()
        return 1
    cursor.close()
```

The first few jsons take ~4 seconds most of this coming from the actual parsing itself and writing to a few other small tables (these aren't causing the slow down), but eventually this process slows way down up to a minute per write and I've checked the "Top SQL" section of my RDS where this postgres DB is hosted and it's definitely writing to this bigger table that is taking up time.

I've tried removing all indexes and foreign keys in this big table and I've also tried removing the conn.commit() until every 300 or so entries. Neither fixes the problem.

Any suggestions or ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: Quick ideas: Have you tried setting the `null` argument of `copy_from` to something else than an empty string ? Have you tried specifying the `size` argument ?

Comment: Can you make your example more self contained?  What is df?  Is that a panda dataframe?

Comment: I can't reproduce a slow down on an unindexed table.  I suspect you missed an index (like maybe the primary key, or a unique index) when you were dropping all of them.  Or maybe you are using an AWS "t" type instance and exhausted your CPU credits, or using burstable IO and exhausted your IO credits.

Comment: I'm definitely not missing an index - but I wonder if AWS is the problem. I currently have a t3.small DB instance, which I've essentially chosen based on the fact I'll be the only person using it at the start and it has enough storage. I have been running a lot on this DB recently though building it out so maybe I have exhausted my credits? Is there a way to check that?

Comment: @GSam11 These are very broad statements/info. It's great that you provided info on what you tried, but if people cannot reproduce your problem, it's hard to tell what the source is.

Comment: I think @jjanes has answered my question. It was an AWS problem not something to do with the code/structure. Once I changed the DB instance to a non-burstable one (db.m5.large) this problem went away! Sorry about the broad overview, I'm new to building out a DBs on RDS/AWS.